# Equivalence of spherical harmonic definitions

Tags: calculus, functions, spherical-harmonics, legendre-functions

In Griffith's "Introduction to quantum mechanics", the spherical harmonics are defined for integers $l$ and $-l\leq m\leq l$ as 
$$Y_{l}^m(\theta,\phi) = \epsilon \sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}\frac{(l-|m|)!}{(l+|m|)!}}e^{im\phi} P_{l}^m (\cos \theta)$$
where $\epsilon=(-1)^m$ for $m\geq 0$ and $\epsilon=1$ for $m\leq 0$.

Also, $$P_{\ell}^m (x) = \frac{(-1)^l}{2^l l!} (1-x^2)^{|m|/2} \left(\frac{d}{dx} \right)^{l+|m|} \left( 1-x^2 \right)^l$$
are the associated Legendre functions. Clearly then

$$P_{\ell}^m (\cos \theta) = \frac{(-1)^l}{2^l l!} \sin^{|m|}\theta \left(\frac{d}{d\cos\theta} \right)^{l+|m|} \sin^{2l} \theta$$ so that $$Y_{l}^m(\theta,\phi) = \epsilon \frac{(-1)^l}{2^l l!} \sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}\frac{(l-|m|)!}{(l+|m|)!}}e^{im\phi} \sin^{|m|}\theta \left(\frac{d}{d\cos\theta} \right)^{l+|m|} \sin^{2l} \theta.$$

Now, other books claim that the Spherical harmonics can be written as

$$Y_{l}^m(\theta,\phi) =  \frac{(-1)^l}{2^l l!} \sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}\frac{(l+m)!}{(l-m)!}}e^{im\phi} \sin^{-m}\theta \left(\frac{d}{d\cos\theta} \right)^{l-m} \sin^{2l} \theta.$$ for any $l,m$, but I cannot see why this is true. Clearly the two become equal for $m \leq 0$, but how to show equivalence for $m \geq 0$?

Comment: By $\frac{d}{d\cos\theta}$ I'm guessing they mean $\frac{1}{-\sin\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}$. Also in both expressions, the derivative is raised to a power, and I see that same power in the denominator of the corresponding expression. Seems suspicious but could be irrelevant for showing equivalence